# How to use the Blender ID in a third-party add-on?

Tags: python, add-on, blender-id

Blender 2.78 came with a perhaps overlooked [feature](https://www.blender.org/features/2-78/) with the [Blender ID authentication](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/System/BlenderID) add-on. It's very strait-forward to use as long as you have registered a [Blender ID](https://www.blender.org/id/about), but I don't see how it can be very useful to third-party developers like the release notes claim.

> Blender 2.78 features the official Blender ID add-on, which allows you
>   to be logged-in within Blender so that other (3rd party) add-ons can
>   provide you with a more tailored experience.

[image]

I can't find any material about how to incorporate this into a third-party add-on (except for the Blender Cloud add-on which really isn't even third-party).

Comment: The Blender Cloud add-on may not be third-party, but it does use the ID in the same way other add-ons would use it (as far as I am aware). Obviously it's not the same as having detailed instructions on how to use it, but it should serve as an example. Maybe @Sybren  can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The readme file in the blender cloud add-on gives more direction. [This page](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BIA/) discusses the simple way to use the Blender ID with your own add-on.

> Using the addon from another addon The following functions can be used
>   from other addons to use the Blender ID functionality:
>
> `blender_id.get_active_profile()` returns the BlenderIdProfile that
>   represents the currently logged in user, or None when the user isn't
>   logged in:
>
> ```
> class BlenderIdProfile:
>     user_id = '41234'
>     username = 'username@example.com'
>     token = '41344124-auth-token-434134'
> ```
>
> `blender_id.get_active_user_id()` returns the user ID of the logged in
>   user, or `''` when the user isn't logged in.
>
> `blender_id.is_logged_in()` returns `True` if the user is logged in,
>   and `False` otherwise.

As is mentioned there, you have access to the user's username (email) and whether or not they are logged in.

---

This is simply a module that you can import:

```
import blender_id

# returns True or False
print(blender_id.is_logged_in())

# user's email username
print(blender_id.get_active_profile().username)
```

Here is a mini demo in Blender's console:

[image]